# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined...'

Tags: android, angular, typescript, sqlite, ionic-framework

Im about to build a Ionic Inventory Management app with Barcode Scanner and SQLite with the help of this tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-cordova-sqlite-barcode-scanner-product-inventory-manager/

When I add this code:

```
 constructor(public sqlite :SQLite) {
          console.log('Hello DataServiceProvider Provider')

              this.sqlite.create({name: "data.db", location: 
    "default"}).then((db : SQLiteObject) => {
                      this.database = db;
                  }, (error) => {
                      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
              });
```

...to data-service.service.ts I got this error:

> core.js:19866 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'then' of undefined
>       at new DataServiceService (data-service.service.ts:64)
>       at _createClass (core.js:26976)
>       at *createProviderInstance (core.js:26941)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26888)
>       at NgModuleRef*.get (core.js:27996)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26908)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27996)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:28518)
>       at createClass (core.js:28366)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:28186)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at zone.js:892
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:21826)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

This is the whole data-service.service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {
  public database: SQLiteObject;

  productTable : string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  products (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    sku TEXT,
    barcode TEXT,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    quantity REAL,
    unit VARCHAR,
    unitPrice REAL,
    minQuantity INTEGER,
    familly_id INTEGER,
    location_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(familly_id) REFERENCES famillies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(location_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
    );`;

familyTable : string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS famillies (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    reference VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    unit VARCHAR);`;

locationTable : string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL);`;
//Date , Quantity , Unit Cost , Reason (New Stock - Usable Return - Unusable Return ) ,UPC (Universal Product Code ) Comment    
transactionTable : string = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        date TEXT,
        quantity REAL,
        unitCost REAL,
        reason VARCHAR,
        upc TEXT,
        comment TEXT,
        product_id INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(id));`;

        async createTables(){
          try {
            await this.database.executeSql(this.familyTable);
            await this.database.executeSql(this.locationTable);
            await this.database.executeSql(this.productTable);
            await this.database.executeSql(this.transactionTable);
          }catch(e){
              console.log("Error !");
          }
      }

        constructor(public sqlite :SQLite) {
          console.log('Hello DataServiceProvider Provider')

              this.sqlite.create({name: "data.db", location: "default"}).then((db : SQLiteObject) => {
                      this.database = db;
                  }, (error) => {
                      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
              }); 
    }

}
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: You are using ionic 4, correct?

Comment: Yes I am using 4.12.0

Comment: And you are testing on device right?

Comment: No, im testing in chrome and getting the mentioned error there.

Comment: How are you running the project? `ionic serve`?

Comment: Yes, and the error appears in the dev console of chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work in browser when running `ionic serve`, because:

As per mentioned [here](https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/846#issuecomment-465878447)

> Cordova needs plugins to run in browser

And they are not added by default. So you can run the project with `ionic cordova run browser`

---

**OR** as mentioned in the comment as well, mock the plugin. [Tried it](https://www.techiediaries.com/mocking-native-sqlite-plugin/) and it worked:

in app module, mock the `create`:

```
import { SQLite  , SQLiteDatabaseConfig , SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

class SQLiteMock {
public create(config: SQLiteDatabaseConfig): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      resolve(new SQLiteObject(new Object()));
    });
  }
}
```

Mark it in providers like:

```
{provide: SQLite, useClass: SQLiteMock},
```

Create a file `sql.js` file in the folder and copy the content from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kripken/sql.js/master/js/sql.js

and add to your index.html:

```
<script src="assets/sql.js"></script>
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

Now your function should work just fine. Going the further steps, I suggest you follow the link I provided before this code, i.e: https://www.techiediaries.com/mocking-native-sqlite-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could look into is whether the constructor is being run before the async function in your code. If so look into implementing something along the lines on ngOnInit.

Comment: How do I implement ngOnInit into the code? I'm sorry, but I am totally new to JS.